# Android ActionBar menu items scrollable

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, android-actionbar, scrollable

I have many sub items under one item in the action bar. Rather than take up the whole page,  How would I make the drop down list scrollable to conserve space?

This is the menu item

```
  <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/airport"
                android:showAsAction="always|withText"
                android:title="Airport"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/atm"
                android:showAsAction="always|withText"
                android:title="Atm"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/bank"
                android:showAsAction="always|withText"
                android:title="Bank"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/bus_station"
                android:showAsAction="always|withText"
                android:title="Bus Station"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/cafe"
                android:showAsAction="always|withText"
                android:title="Cafe"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/doctor"
                android:showAsAction="always|withText"
                android:title="Doctor"/>
              <item
                android:id="@+id/food"
                android:showAsAction="always|withText"
                android:title="Food"/>
               <item
                android:id="@+id/hospital"
                android:showAsAction="always|withText"
                android:title="Hospital"/>

        </menu>
    </item>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `configrations` of your `actionBar` as the following:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setNavigationMode(NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(mSpinnerAdapter, mNavigationCallback);
```

Here is a similar [Example](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Dropdown) that do what you want